# Error in the flash builder 4.5 when changing visible value in app-xml file

Tags: flash-builder

I am using flash builder 4.5 to create an app. when I changer the initial window - visible value in app- xml, I am not able to run the app. I get the following error

"Process terminated unexpectedly.

invalid application descriptor: Illegal value "true
false" for application/initialWindow/visible.

Launch command details:  "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\sdks\4.5.1\bin\adl.exe" -runtime "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\sdks\4.5.1\runtimes\air\win" "C:\Documents and Settings\preevara\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\Test\bin-debug\Test-app.xml" "C:\Documents and Settings\preevara\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\Test\bin-debug"  "

why is this error thrown

Answer (score 0):

Just one year later but I've got the same issue and the solution is : check your xx-app.xml, this message appear when you have more than one tag.
I've found this  in my app.xml :

```
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
    <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
    <visible>false</visible>
</initialWindow>
```